# The model backing the 'EFDbContext' context has changed error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

Following the sports store tutorial in `Pro Asp.Net MVC book,` 
I have TWO projects in my Asp.Net MVC4 solution. One `SportsStore.WebUI` and one `SportsStore.Domain` , which has my Product class below

I added a Required attribute to `Name` in my model class

```
    //Product.cs class
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //..more properties, not important as I get the same error for all -
   because I added Required to all
```

When I run the project I get `The model backing the 'EFDbContext' context has changed since the database was created.` error.

I have checked on stackoverflow and MSDN

**Solution 1: Didn't Work**

Suggested solution on MSDN  was to run `Update-Database -Force` . That doesn't work , I get

*"Could not load assembly 'SportsStore.WebUI'. (If you are using Code First Migrations inside Visual Studio this can happen if the startUp project for your solution does not reference the project that contains your migrations. You can either change the startUp project for your solution or use the -StartUpProjectName parameter.)"*

That is strange because A- I'm NOT using code first and B-The Domain project DOES reference WebUI project

**Solution 2: Didn't Work**

Then I tried `Enable-Migrations` in the PM console and I get

```
No context type was found in the assembly 'SportsStore.WebUI'.
```

I then tried changing the startup project to SportsStore.Domain ( which has my product class) - nothing, same error

Comment: I dont understand. You are editing Product.cs but you are not using Code-First?

Comment: No I'm not using Code first, there is no edmx at all. Just a connection string in Web.COnfig, a DBContext class manually written and the above product class :(

Comment: The code in the book you are referring to IS code first, but it hides it by creating the tables first; when code first goes to create the tables, they already exist. This isn't related to the error, however.

Comment: Oh.sorry I thought code first refererred to using Edmx. But still the databse was created BEFORE the product.cs was written

Comment: You are working in reverse. You want to use entity framework, but you dont want to let him create your database or your model. You only use it for the connection.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is actually occurring because you didn't change the target for your invocation of the scaffolding.  In the Package Manager Console, when you run any commands which target your Domain objects, the Default Project dropdown needs to be set to your Domain project.  If you try to run migrations or database updates against your web project, they will fail.

**Edit**

Important is this line in the error

> If you are using Code First Migrations inside Visual Studio this can happen if the startUp project for your solution does not reference the project that contains your migrations.

the error suggests `"Could not load assembly 'SportsStore.WebUI'` which means that's the project the migrations were put in, even though they should have gone in your Domain Project.

Comment: Thanks. It was as simple as choosing the right project from the drop down. But when you don't know where to look , everything is invisible. :)

Comment: If you cannot see the Default Project dropdown in the package manager console, widen the splitter somewhat until it comes into view. (It is not partially visible, and there is no hint of it whatsoever, unless you do this: it only becomes visible when completely stretched out. I just waster 1/2 hour trying to figure this annoyance out).

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error. I had an existing asp.net mvc using EF 5.0 that was working fine.

I then created a console app with EF 5.0 that pointed to the same database. The asp.net mvc app started throwing the model backing exception.

I noticed there was a new table named "_*MigrationHistory". To get the asp.net app working again, I renamed this table "*_MigrationHistory_backup"